# How to find text of UILabel which is set in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I have `UILabel *lblTest`. and I set text to this label as "test" in `Interface Builder`.

now I set lblTest text as "new test" through code.

So now again I want to get "test" text which I already set in `Interface Builder`.

Is there any way to do this smartly?

**NOTE :** I am not interested to do number of line code.... 
       Expecting single line solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you set label text " new text " through code in your viewdidload then it will always show "new text" until and unless either you give label text as "test" or comment your line

Comment: You overwrite "test" with "new test" and want to find "test" which it was previously set to?  How many iterations do you need to go back?  Can you use .placeholder for initial string?

Comment: @:Bejmax I am expecting something like this code "[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(NSString *)[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]]"

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you want to do?

Comment: It does not have to be on one line to be "smart" like you say. However, keep on expecting the "one line" solution. I'm sure it will be a very beautiful and smart piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that that the values in your **Interface Builder** will be overwritten by the code code you've wrote yourself.

So once your code has changed the label, you can revert the value of the **Interface Builder** like:

```
NSString* lblTestString = lblTestString.text;

//now set your value from the code
[lblTest setText:@"new Test"];

//and revert it to what was already in the interface builder
[lblTest setText:lblTestString];
```

Still it doesn't make any sense really..

Comment: That I already considered last way to do same. but I am expecting single line solution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like an "Undo" functionality.
There is no special way to do the thing you describe.
One thing you can do is:

1. Store the first string in an NSString variable before you set the label text as "new test"

   ```
   NSString *oldString = lblTest.text;
   ```
2. Change the text from code.

   ```
   self.lblTest.text = @"new test";
   ```
3. When you want, change it back to the old string.

   ```
   self.lblTest.text = oldString;
   ```